# Test of independence between continuous variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have done bivariate analysis in between two different pairs of predictors and in first case gets coefficient of correlation=0.7 and P-value>0.05 and in second case, gets coefficient of correlation=0.2 and p value <0.05. My question is:-
(i) for case one, predictors are highly correlated but not significant. What does it mean? 
(ii) for case second, predictors are less correlated but high significant. So are they useful for model?

Comment: What was your sample size in each case?

Comment: Why do you care whether the correlations differ from zero? Surely, to the extent that correlations between predictors matter at all, it's *how* correlated they are (or more specifically the effect of that on your regression) - not its p-value - that's at issue.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for your reply. I want to ask the approach for model is that firstly we perform statistics test in between the predictors in order to check multicollinearity and if it exists then remove the predictor which is less correlated to target variable and secondly we perform test in between predictors and response variables individually. Is this correct approach?

Comment: 1. You *don't* need independence, so why check for it? 2. Having low correlation between all predictors doesn't mean you don't have multicollinearity. .... testing answers the wrong question, and the premise of the methodology you're using is wrong. Where did you get it from?

Comment: I'm just bit confused regarding the statistics tests need to perform in between predictors and between predictors and response variable.Can you brief it what tests we need to follow?

Answer (score 1):

> for case one, predictors are highly correlated but not significant.
>   What does it mean?

It usually means small sample size.

> for case second, predictors are less
>   correlated but high significant. So are they useful for model?

I'd use VIF (Variance Inflation Factor) to check this. Rule of thumb says variables with VIF>10 shouldn't be used in model.

Comment: But I have sample size of 100k.. isn't sufficient to check predictors independency?

Comment: Slightly dependent predictors are not a problem in regression. Don't ask me, please, what "slightly" means. I use VIF to avoid this question :)

Comment: Okey so you are telling test for multicollinearity is the best way to check independence in between predictors rather then to check individually test(pearson in this case) for each pair of predictors?

Comment: I believe it is the best way to eliminate predictors that cause multicollinearity problems. VIF deos not check for independece!

Comment: So what could be best way for checking independence in between variables?

Comment: Correlation, but this is not the same as checking if they can be used in regression together.